# Is there a way to package an ASP.NET REST Service made in .NET Framework 4.8 into a DLL?

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2022, .net-4.8

I have created an ASP.NET REST API with Swagger.  But that is basically just a console application.
I need to have it encapsulated within a DLL so that I can integrate it with an already existing .net Windows Service.  Is there a way to do that?  There are so many files and folders within the ASP.NET project that I am not certain just copying files to the windows service project would be a clean solution to this issue.

I have tried to create a DLL with all of the code files for a .NET Core ASP.NET REST Service but when i called the code that was in the 'Application_Start' section it did not throw errors (that i could see) and it also did not expose the endpoint.

Comment: It depends on whether you use additional local files. To build the DLL, you can start with the class library project.